# How to make product url-key with capital letters

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I am trying to make my product url-keys in capital letters. Even if I update it manually it is still showing all in lower case letters. Upon checking the url-key after saving the product again it is auto saved in lower case. Is there anything I can do to force all product urls to be in capital letters?

Comment: That the url keys are in lower case happens here: `\Magento\Framework\Filter\TranslitUrl::filter` that's probably a good starting point. Be aware if you change the `strtolower` to `strtoupper` it will apply to all url keys (e.g. categories). You might have to add a new filter to `\Magento\Framework\Filter\Factory` and use this specific one for all product url key generations

Comment: I've tried to change the functio as you suggested from strtolower to strtoupper but I receive: **Unique constraint violation found** when I try to save a product with the new url-key. I believe this is due to the fact that I have to truncate the tables **catalog_url_rewrite_product_category** and **URL_rewrite** still not sure dough.

Comment: This might be because the same url key is already present just in lower case (I had this problem). You could try deleting the key and save the product then magento should generate one in upper case. But as I said if you change it in this function be aware you'll change all generated urls because magento is using it for categories as well.